# How do I backup my bookmarklets?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, backup, bookmarks

Any ideas how to backup bookmarklets so I can install them on a new machine?  I'm thinking specifically of Chrome -- but I'd like to know how to do the same with Firefox too.

Comment: Are you making a certain distinction between *bookmarks* and *bookmarklets*?

Comment: Bookmarklets are just bookmarks that contain JavaScript code to be executed instead of a URL to open when clicked. So you want to backup *bookmarks*, or *some of your bookmarks*

Comment: I want the whole shebang. Bookmarks, bookmarklets, etc.  I've just setup Chrome on a new machine.  Thanks all for the speedy responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To export your bookmarks on Chrome, you can go into the Bookmarks Manager (Bookmarks menu -> Bookmarks Manager) and in the *Organize* menu, click *Export Bookmarks*. This will give you an HTML file that both Firefox and Chrome will be able to import. (To import them back into Chrome, follow the same steps, but click *Import Bookmarks* and locate the bookmarks file).

To export your bookmarks on Firefox, click on *Organize Bookmarks* in the Bookmarks menu (may be called *Manage Bookmarks*). Go to the File menu and click *Export* (or *Import and Backup*), and save the HTML file that way.

Comment: You are fast! I'm trying to 'accept your answer' -- but even SU thinks I'm doing so too fast, & won't let me.

Comment: @Rolnik Thanks! :) It'll let you accept it soon, no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you click on the 'customize button' (looks like a wrench), and follow these steps:

1. BookMark manager
2. Export bookmarks

I just tried this, and stored the result to a network drive, so I can use it on a newer computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to at least three different computers then using a cloud is enough for your purposes. The cloud will serve as backup too.

If all you want is to copy bookmarks from machine A to machine B, you can use the cloud as well.

A popular one, though not open-source, is xmarks.

Comment: If you want to sync bookmarks between 2 or more computers xmarks is a great option. If you want to do a one-off transfer go with the export feature already recommended

Comment: Yes, but why not doing a one-off job that will automatically keep you synchronized forever?