# How to backup and restore my bookmarks in firefox?

Tags: firefox, backup, restore, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I backup my bookmarklets?](https://superuser.com/questions/230984/how-do-i-backup-my-bookmarklets)

My Firefox has some problem. So I wants to reinstall my firefox browser. But saved bookmarks in that firefox are needed in future. Can anyone help me, how to store those bookmarks and restore them after reinstall of firefox?

Answer (score 2):

See Firefox help for [bookmarks](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/how-do-i-use-bookmarks?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Bookmarks)

Answer (score 0):

What about Firefox plugin [Xmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xmarks-sync/)?

Answer (score 0):

[Firefox Sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/firefox-sync/) might do what you need. It will keep you bookmarks synchronized online through different installations of Firefox. Unfortunately it's not cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xMarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) extension. It can not only save all your bookmarks, but even synchronize them between different Firefox instances.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another idead (I have used or still use any of the above):
There's a handy little tool called [MozBackup](http://www.mozbackup.de/) that, well, backs up and restores complete Firefox and Thunderbird profiles. It's kind of a 90s version of all those sync solutions, but at times, it comes in handy when you really want to transfer complete profiles and syncing (for whatever reason) isn't an option.
Plus it works for Thunderbird, too, which as far as I know hasn't any sync options.